# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 2D game Development

Tags: java, 2d-games

i was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND543iriRuE&index=5&list=PLmnre1rRSPjEbhc9JcIC5bwnazdjnL_L1) but i don't know where is the error the following 2 class are explaining every thing because it's only two class i tried to watch the tutorial again but still i did not find the error

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gameofthrones;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author issba
 */
public class ClassOGP extends JFrame{
    boolean fse =false;
    int fsm = 0;
    GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];
    public ClassOGP(String title,int width,int height){
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width,height);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);


    }

    private void setfullscreen(){
        switch(fsm){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("No fullscreen");
                setUndecorated(false);
            break;
            case 1:
                setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                setUndecorated(true);
            break;
            case 2:
                device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                setUndecorated(true);
            break;
        }

    }

    public void setFullscreen(int fsnm){
           fse = true;
           if(fsm <= 2){
           this.fsm = fsnm;
           setfullscreen();
           }else{
           System.err.println("Error " + fsnm + " is not supported");
           }
        }
    }
```

this is the main class there is no much code in it.

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package gameofthrones;


/**
 *
 * @author issba
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassOGP frame = new ClassOGP("Game Of thrones",1280,720);
        frame.setFullscreen(1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

the error message here

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at gameofthrones.ClassOGP.<init>(ClassOGP.java:18)
    at gameofthrones.Main.main(Main.java:20)
C:\Users\issba\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: This line: `GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];` is throwing the error. Try changing the `1` to a `0`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly right thank you man if you like you can post it as answer also can you enplane the different plz

Comment: @Siddharth thank u man for editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[1];
```

Is throwing the error. Try changing the `1` to a `0`.

That is a just a quick fix though, you should declare the device as an instance or class member and assign it in the constructor. Then you can do error checking if there are no screen devices. Like the following:

```
public class ClassOGP extends JFrame{
    /* other code */

    public GraphicsDevice device;

    public ClassOGP(String title,int width,int height) {
        if(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices().length() > 0) {
            // you can also check for multiple devices here to see if you want
            // to use one other than the zero'th index
            device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No devices ... exiting.");
            System.exit();
        }

        /* other code */
    }

    /* rest of class */
}
```

Comment: thank you for your addition but i am still newbie and i am following the tutorial so thank you for your help  i added credit for u

Comment: Thank you for the +1 and marking my answer as accepted. If another user provides more insight and adds a better answer, I won't mind if you change to their answer being accepted.

Comment: do u know how to make my code (same code) use the number 1 also as device

Comment: It depends on how many screen devices you have, apparently you only have 1 screen device. Since when you try to access index 1 of the returned array it throws an index out of bounds exception. Array indexes  start at 0, so the first element would be at index 0 and the second element would be at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you try to access an element with an illegal array index or which is outside outside the scope of the array.